# How do I connect to a wireless network using a TP-Link TL-WN321G USB adapter

Tags: wireless, usb

I'm having troubles connecting to the Internet with my new wireless USB adapter. Although I can see via the NetworkManager all the wireless networks around me, it fails to connect to any of them.
I'm using Linux Mint 10 RC.
I've blacklisted the rt2500usb driver because it was loaded simultaneously with rt73usb.

Here is the output of lsmod:

```
nls_iso8859_1           3261  1 
nls_cp437               4931  1 
vfat                    9201  1 
fat                    48240  1 vfat
usb_storage            40172  1 
nls_utf8                1069  1 
isofs                  30022  1 
aes_i586                7280  0 
aes_generic            26875  1 aes_i586
binfmt_misc             6599  1 
dm_crypt               11385  0 
arc4                    1165  2 
snd_intel8x0           25632  2 
snd_ac97_codec         99227  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus                1014  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm                71475  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec
rt73usb                22442  0 
snd_seq_midi            4588  0 
crc_itu_t               1383  1 rt73usb
rt2x00usb               9779  1 rt73usb
rt2x00lib              27275  2 rt73usb,rt2x00usb
snd_rawmidi            17783  1 snd_seq_midi
led_class               2633  1 rt2x00lib
mac80211              231541  2 rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
snd_seq_midi_event      6047  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                47174  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              19067  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device          5744  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
ppdev                   5556  0 
cfg80211              144470  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
parport_pc             26058  1 
snd                    49006  11 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
shpchp                 29886  0 
soundcore                880  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          7120  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
lp                      7342  0 
parport                31492  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
dm_raid45              81721  0 
xor                    15136  1 dm_raid45
btrfs                 489451  0 
zlib_deflate           19266  1 btrfs
crc32c                  2531  1 
libcrc32c                887  1 btrfs
usbhid                 36882  0 
hid                    67742  1 usbhid
i915                  290938  3 
drm_kms_helper         30200  1 i915
drm                   168054  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
floppy                 54311  0 
e1000                  97525  0 
intel_agp              26360  2 i915
i2c_algo_bit            5168  1 i915
video                  18712  1 i915
output                  1883  1 video
agpgart                32011  2 drm,intel_agp

nls_iso8859_1           3261  1 
nls_cp437               4931  1 
vfat                    9201  1 
fat                    48240  1 vfat
usb_storage            40172  1 
nls_utf8                1069  1 
isofs                  30022  1 
aes_i586                7280  0 
aes_generic            26875  1 aes_i586
binfmt_misc             6599  1 
dm_crypt               11385  0 
arc4                    1165  2 
snd_intel8x0           25632  2 
snd_ac97_codec         99227  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus                1014  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm                71475  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec
rt73usb                22442  0 
snd_seq_midi            4588  0 
crc_itu_t               1383  1 rt73usb
rt2x00usb               9779  1 rt73usb
rt2x00lib              27275  2 rt73usb,rt2x00usb
snd_rawmidi            17783  1 snd_seq_midi
led_class               2633  1 rt2x00lib
mac80211              231541  2 rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
snd_seq_midi_event      6047  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                47174  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              19067  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device          5744  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
ppdev                   5556  0 
cfg80211              144470  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
parport_pc             26058  1 
snd                    49006  11 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
shpchp                 29886  0 
soundcore                880  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          7120  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
lp                      7342  0 
parport                31492  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
dm_raid45              81721  0 
xor                    15136  1 dm_raid45
btrfs                 489451  0 
zlib_deflate           19266  1 btrfs
crc32c                  2531  1 
libcrc32c                887  1 btrfs
usbhid                 36882  0 
hid                    67742  1 usbhid
i915                  290938  3 
drm_kms_helper         30200  1 i915
drm                   168054  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
floppy                 54311  0 
e1000                  97525  0 
intel_agp              26360  2 i915
i2c_algo_bit            5168  1 i915
video                  18712  1 i915
output                  1883  1 video
agpgart                32011  2 drm,intel_agp
```

Output of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0d:60:ae:4f:df  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9120 (9.1 KB)  TX bytes:9120 (9.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:5d:4c:89:7c:d8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::da5d:4cff:fe89:7cd8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17137 (17.1 KB)  TX bytes:6535 (6.5 KB)
```

Output of lshw -C Network:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82541EI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: b
       bus info: pci@0000:03:0b.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:0d:60:ae:4f:df
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k6-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=52 mingnt=255 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:16 memory:e8100000-e811ffff ioport:2000(size=64)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:7
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: d8:5d:4c:89:7c:d8
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt73usb driverversion=2.6.35-22-generic firmware=N/A multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
```

The output of cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

The output of iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Tx-Power=9 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

The output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82865G/PE/P DRAM Controller/Host-Hub Interface (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 82865G/PE/P Processor to I/O Memory Interface (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
03:0b.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82541EI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

As requested here is the output of lsusb

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04b3:3108 IBM Corp. 800dpi Optical Mouse w/ Scroll Point
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 090c:1000 Feiya Technology Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:2573 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2501/RT2573 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can somebody help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

As suggested by outofstep, I downloaded the RT2501USB(RT73:RT2571W/RT2573/RT2671) firmware from http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501 and copied the file rt73.bin to /lib/firmware unplugged the usb adapter, plugged it in again but to no avail. A reboot of the computer didn't help either. But thanks anyway.

This is the output of dmesg | grep rt73

```
[   15.540677] Registered led device: rt73usb-phy0::radio
[   15.540720] Registered led device: rt73usb-phy0::assoc
[   15.540763] Registered led device: rt73usb-phy0::quality
[   15.541515] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt73usb
```

Thanks for the support so far, outofstep and hhlp.

Comment: lsusb is more usefull in this case than lspci can you update your post with this information .. regards.,

Comment: Are Linux mint questions allowed here?

Comment: Keep an eye on http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-on-topic for more information on questions about Linux Mint on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @Shubh: This question isn't regarding Linux Mint. Problems with this wireless adapter affect Ubuntu users as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I finally established an Internet connection. And the way I fixed the problem is ridiculous: I plugged the USB adapter into one of the *rear* USB ports. When plugged into the front side bus the wireless networks were detected but I was unable to connect to any of them as described in my question. Also the adapter doesn't seem to work when plugged in while booting. It has to be plugged into one of the rear USB ports after start up.
This is mind boggling.

Anyway, although it might seem funny: Plugging the TP-Link TL-WN321G USB adapter into one of the rear USB ports instead of the front side bus made the thing connecting to a wireless network.
In what way the firmware update has contributed to the solution I can't tell. Thanks to all of you for your help.